# Vagrant package does not include files with --include

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am packaging a Vagrant box with `vagrant package --base mybox --output mybox.box --vagrantfile ./Vagrantfile`.

This works fine, and I uploaded the box to Vagrant Cloud.

I am then running `vagrant login`, followed by `vagrant init myrepo/mybox`, which leads to:

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes/[removed]/mybox/0.0.2/virtualbox/include/_Vagrantfile:5: warning: already initialized constant VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION

Vagrantfile:5: warning: previous definition of VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION was here. There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* `path` for shell provisioner does not exist on the host system:   
[pwd]/test/provision/a_provision_file.sh
```

~ and pwd are home and the empty directory I provisioned in, respectively. `a_provision_file.sh` should have been included because I passed `--include=provision/` to `vagrant package`. I'm confused as to why this file is not present in the box that was uploaded to Vagrant Cloud.

Thank you.